# Convert BigDecimal to String in Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, bigdecimal

The `.toString()` method does work on `BigDecimal`, but I can't seem to get it to work when I'm looping through an array and referencing it with `array[i]`. Here's my code, where *numb* is a string variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    if((b[i].getClass().toString().contains("String") || b[i].getClass().toString().contains("BigDecimal"))&& isNumeric((String)b[i]) && i != b.length-1){ 
        if(!caught){
            caught = true;
            startIndex = i; //where the number starts
            }
            numb+=b[i].toString();
```

And the error message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is probably due to this cast:

```
(String)b[i]
```

Replace it with

```
b[i].toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

`b[i]` can contain the type `BigInteger`. You're attempting to cast a type of `BigInteger` to a `String` using an explicit cast. This is not possible using this syntax. Instead, if the type is `BigInteger`, you can convert in the following way:

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger("444");
String stringVal = bigInt.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast a `BigDecimal` to a `String` using an explicit cast, simply because a `BigDecimal` is not a `String`.

It depends of how your `isNumeric` method is implemented* but you have to do :

```
isNumeric(b[i].toPlainString())
```

*because `toString()` can use scientific notation if an exponent is needed.

Answer (score 1):

`isNumeric((String)b[i])`

Change this as

`isNumeric(b[i].toString())`

you cannot convert an `Object` to a `String` by casting.

Answer (score 1):

you could also try String.valueOf(b[i]);